# Javascript Conflict in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, calendar

I am using this extension on my magento store .
Extension :http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/event-calendar-1.html

This is the event page on my store : www.alshulauae.com/events

But the custom javascript for this theme http://alshulauae.com/skin/frontend/default/MAG090176/js/custom.js  is conflict with the extension and the event calendar is not showing .
If I remove the custom.js  , the calendar show properly .
Any help how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in console.log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `local.xml` file, first remove all the js files from the page (using handler - controller), and then again add in the correct order that you want. This will solve any dependency conflict issues.